# defining a global function in kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I am new to kohana and also relatively to php.

I have a simple URI encoding function, which mimics that of JS %100, unlike that of PHP's.

I want to use this function in certain classes but I don't want to define it in each and every one of them.

So, how can I define a global function to be used in all places?

(I don't want to create a class for a 3 line code function)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Overload the core [URL](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/URL) helper class. Add your function as a static method.

Answer (score 2):

Override your desire to avoid good OO principles.  Create a new class and make a static public function.  Don't create bad-old global functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function yourFunction( ) {
    return 'your result';
}
```

How about that? Just write that in a file that always gets included and you're good to go. Don't go making a static class just for the sake of thinking you're doing OO, there's no point.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your global function in you bootstrap (`APPPATH/bootstrap.php`) though I recommend extending the core URL helper class (assuming you're on Kohana 3.x) by creating a new file at `APPPATH/classes/url.php`:

```
class URL extends Kohana_URL {

    public static function encode($uri)
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

It's almost always worth the 3 lines of code. Kohana was designed for you to override its core classes. Your code will be more maintainable.